# Windows 7 "you need to format the disk in drive.."

Tags: windows-7, usb

my old HDD was dying and it seems somehow it screwed some drivers in the process. Suddenly I'm getting "You need to format the disk in drive x: before you can use it" whenever I plug ANY usb disk (and they all work on other systems, so no, no problems with drives; even kindle dows not work).

I've managed to "repair" the bad sectors with seatools and duplicate the disk (using linux dd) on a new one (same model).

Everything seems to work ok, just this *bliping* error. I've tried google but I see many threads with this problems and no solution.

Ideas?

Update: NTFS external drive does work, but none of the fat do. So I guess my fat driver is broken. Which dll do I need to replace?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

- Start->All Programs->Accessories->Right click Command Prompt, Run As Admin
- sfc /scannow
- wait (it has a nice little progress bar, but it takes forever)